# Восстановление после побитового сдвига

Tags: c++

Дан массив char-ов, который сдвинут на 3 бита вправо. Каким образом можно сдвинуть его назад (т.е. применить операцию сдвига влево на 3 бита), но при этом восстановить исходные значения, до сдвига вправо? Есть ли готовые алгоритмы? Если что, то вот моя попытка решения:

```
inFile.read(frame,sizeOfFrame);
char b; char result1;
char temp = 0;

for (int i = sizeOfFrame; i >0; i--)
    {
b = (char)frame[i-1];
result1 = (char)b<<3;
char tmp_val = ((result1 + temp) & 0xFF);
temp = result1>>8;
frameDest[i-1] = tmp_val;
    }
```

Comment: @MartinSeptim, а откуда Вы возьмете первоначальное значение самых правых 3-х бит?

Comment: @avp, немного не понял ваш вопрос. В frame уже сдвинутые на 3 бита вправо char. Для того чтобы узнать точно ли восстановились данные я знаю какими должны быть первые 6 символов из frameDest. Т.е. если верны первые 6 символов, то и верны все остальные.

Comment: @MartinSeptim что-то непонятно. Как отмечает @avp, что упало -- то пропало. 

Вы свою программу проверяли? В temp значения либо 0x00, либо 0xff (в зависимости от старшего бита result1. Понять Ваш код сложно. Что значит

      Дан массив char-ов, который сдвинут на 3 бита вправо

Т.е. младшие 3 бита каждого байта переходят в следующий байт или теряются? Но в любом варианте есть потерянные биты, которые неоткуда восстановить.

Comment: @alexlz, вот и я про то же. 

--

@MartinSeptim программу сдвига *вправо* (результат работы которой Вы "восстанавливаете") опубликуйте.

Comment: Создайте массив остатков от деления на 8. И после "восстановительного" сдвига влево добавьте к результатам. В случае опубликования (по @avp) настаиваю на соавторстве.

Comment: Судя по всему я неправильно понял задание и неверно его выполнил. Для создания эффекта переноса вправо я использовал следующий код:
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeOfFrame;i++)
    {
    frame[i] = (char)frame[i]>>3;
    }
, что в корне неверно, т.к. я сдвигаю каждый байт массива отдельно. А по заданию весь массив сдвинут вправо.

Comment: @MartinSeptim, учтите, что при таком сдвиге, как Вы написали левые 3 бита будут равны биту знака (например, для русских букв все 3 будут 1).

Вам, собственно, какой сдвиг-то нужен ("логический" или "арифметический")?

--

P.S.  если будете советоваться, то лучше напишите пару примеров с нулями и единичками.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define rol(value, bits) (((value) << (bits)) | (((value) & 0xff) >> (8 - (bits))))
```

Comment: @Veliant, Вы обратили внимание

    Дан массив char-ов, который сдвинут на 3 бита вправо

при чем здесь *циклический сдвиг* **влево** одного байта?

Comment: неправильно понял вопрос

b = frame[i-1];
char tmp_val = (b<<3 & 0xFF) | temp;
temp = b>>5;
frameDest[i-1] = tmp_val;

Comment: @Veliant,  для `signed` надо писать

   temp = (b >> 5) & 0x1f;

т.к. знаковый бит при сдвиге *вправо* распространяется, а Вам нужны именно 3 предыдущих левых бита. 

Конечно, все это можно записать и короче

    char prev3bits = 0;
    for (int i = sizeOfFrame; i > 0; i--) {
       frameDest[i - 1] = (frame[i - 1] << 3) | prev3bits;
       prev3bits = (unsigned char)frame[i - 1] >> 5;
    }

Но, это не решает проблему "потерянных" при предыдущем *сдвиге вправо* 3-х бит в `frame[sizeOfFrame - 1]` (мы можем **только предположить**, что это нули).